# What does SettingWithCopyWarning mean?

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to create a variable to my dataset that returns a 1 if TimeLogDlyOpsID = previous(TimeLogDlyOpsID).  Otherwise returns 0.  I know how to do this in R, but am trying to recreate it in Python.

```
for i in range(2,len(tmpTimeLog2)):
    if(tmpTimeLog2.TimeLogDlyOpsID[i] == tmpTimeLog2.TimeLogDlyOpsID[i-1]):
        tmpTimeLog2.test[i] = '1'
    else:
        tmpTimeLog2.test[i] = '0'
```

I get the following warning message:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you getting a "SettingWithCopyWarning" before the error?

Comment: Victor S, Yes I am